# What to watch in our next movie night?

Tags: discussion, chat-event, movie-night

So movie night was a total success. I'll be transcribing it into a blog post in a day or so.

What do we wanna watch at the next gathering in 2 weeks?

I was thinking a movie this time. I liked watching episodes of Star Trek and I'm sure we'll be doing some more episodes of some show or another soon, but since this is still going through the beta phase, I want to test the waters with a different type of media.

Suggestions are open. The format of the chat is of course humor, so please suggest something that can be fun to rip on while watching.

Comment: How did the last one go? Got a link?

Comment: @Wikis The full transcript is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2158).

Comment: Anything that stars Marvin the Martian!

Answer (score 5):

Firefly could be an interesting series to try.

Answer (score 2):

[Ghost in the Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_%28film%29). Classic, awesome, and likely something a lot of this site's audience hasn't seen.

Comment: Someone likes anime lol

Comment: Bahaha, I just think we should have more anime content on this site!

Comment: We are trying to limit what we watch to what's available on Netflix, as it almost garuntees that people all over the world will have access to it.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris You mean people all over America, right? :p

Comment: Netflix is in Canada, Australia and England, isn't it?

Comment: But the licensing isn't the same everywhere.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris no, Netflix isn't in Australia.  It's available in the Americas and IIRC launched in the UK today.

Answer (score 2):

[Akira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_%28film%29) would also be a great movie to screen. Dystopic, futuristic, and featuring lots of violence and motor vehicles. Amazing film.

Comment: Picking a film that I've not only heard of but even seen? Crazy!

Answer (score 2):

Anything by [Hayao Miyazaki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayao_Miyazaki). In recent memory, *Spirited Away*, *Howl's Moving Castle*, and *Ponyo* were hits in the U.S. His other films include *Princess Mononoke*, *Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind*, *Laputa: Castle in the Sky*, *Kiki's Delivery Service*, and *My Neighbor Totoro*.

Answer (score 1):

Episode I or III of Star Wars.

Noooooooooooo!

Answer (score 1):

[Paprika](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paprika_%282006_film%29) is a real audience-pleaser, especially in a post-Inception world.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had a great time watching either sci-fi or horror B-movies (or "bad" A-movies), and I imagine lots of folks have had a similar experiences.  Off the top of my head, I'd love to do a Godzilla movie (not the American one, of course).

Answer (score -2):

We could go ahead and just watch some Mystery Science Theater 3000!

[image: MST3K]

Comment: But we can't do an MST3K on MST3K... That's too meta.